# Server-Sent Event Not Working on Host Server but Working on Localhost

Tags: javascript, express, push-notification, server-sent-events

Express JS server-sent event not functioning on live server, but works locally.I initially thought the problem is the token sent by the client. but when i checked, right token is being send.
The server has a status code of 503.

backend-server code

````
   
  res.set({
    "Content-Type": "text/event-stream",
    "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
  });

  try {
    const readusers = await ReadComments.find({});
    if (!readusers) {
      return res.status(404).send("No comments found");
    }

    // Send the initial data to the client
    res.write(`data: ${JSON.stringify(readusers)}\n\n`);

    // Set up an interval to send updates to the client
    const intervalId = setInterval(async () => {
      const updatedData = await ReadComments.find({});
      res.write(`data: ${JSON.stringify(updatedData)}\n\n`);
    }, 3000);

    // When the client closes the connection, clear the interval
    req.on("close", () => {
      clearInterval(intervalId);
    });
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(500).send(error.message);
  }
});```
 

client code

  ```useEffect(() => {
 
      let source = new EventSource(`https://crowded-turtleneck-eel.cyclic.app/comment?token=${localstorageToken}`,{
  
      });
      source.onmessage = async(event) => {
        let parsedEventData=await JSON.parse(event.data).filter((filterdMovie)=>{
           return filterdMovie.movieId === props.reviewProps.id
        })
       const sortedArray = sortByCreatedAt(parsedEventData)
        setFeedCard(sortedArray)
        
      };
    }, []);
````